# Variables in gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I just began with the implementation of CI jobs using gitlab-ci and I'm trying to create a job template. Basically the job uses the same image, tags and script where I use variables:

```
.job_e2e_template: &job_e2e
  stage: e2e-test
  tags:
   - test
  image: my_image_repo/siderunner
  script:
    - selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=$JOB_BROWSER" --server http://${SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST}:${SELENIUM_HUB_PORT}/wd/hub --output-directory docker/selenium/out_$FOLDER_POSTFIX docker/selenium/tests/*.side;
```

And here is one of the jobs using this anchor:

```
test-chrome:
  <<: *job_e2e
  variables:
    JOB_BROWSER: "chrome"
    FOLDER_POSTFIX: "chrome"
  services:
    - selenium-hub
    - node-chrome
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - tests/
      - out_chrome/
```

I'd like this template to be more generic and I was wondering if I could also use variables in the services and artifacts section, so I could add a few more lines in my template like this:

```
      services:
        - selenium-hub
        - node-$JOB_BROWSER
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - tests/
          - out_$JOB_BROWSER/
```

However I cannot find any example of that and the doc only talks about using that in scripts. I know that variables are like environment variables for jobs but I'm not sure if they can be used for other purposes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes you can. Like described in this [blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/10/01/three-yaml-tips-better-pipelines/), gitlab does a deep merge based on the keys.

You can see how your merged pipeline file looks like under `CI/CD` -> `Editor` -> `View merged YAML`.

If you want to modularize your pipeline even further I would recommend using [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) instead of yaml anchors, so you can reuse your templates in different pipelines.